# Centre elements positioned using CSS fixed positioning

Tags: asp.net, css

Not able to centre elements positioned using CSS "top and left and postion:fixed attributes".

Comment: Can you post the code you tried so far?

Comment: tried center ta, align tag, tired putting the divs in table then center table, center tble cell nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position fixed places the element in reference to the browser, not parent elements.  See this excerpt regarding position:fixed -

> Generates an absolutely positioned
>   element, positioned relative to the
>   browser window. The element's position
>   is specified with the "left", "top",
>   "right", and "bottom" properties

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)

You likely want to use `position: relative`, but without source it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add the class *centee* to the thing you want to center. Wrap it around a container with class *centerer*. The container will not be visible.

**HTML**

```
<div class="centerer">
 <div class="centee"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.centerer {
 position: fixed;
 left: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px; 
}

 .centee {
  position: absolute;
  width: 555px;
  height: 333px;
  margin-left: -50%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  background: blue;
 }
```